# Why do Magento configurable products have a SKU

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I am about to create about 300 products (not many but enough).  Most of them are configurable so I will be entering a bunch of info then putting it together.  Each simple product that makes up a config product has its own sku, so why would a configurable product need a sku?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SKU is a primary key that does not rely on automatically generated db indexes although when dealing with bundles you can generate the SKU dynamically.

Main reason for that is to gain database irrelevance and enable easy import and export of database contents (cause the items are not identified by auto id's and such that will give troubles if imported and exported and increment id's or duplicates already exist)

So for configurable products you still need SKU to identify the group of products or the range of products that can be configured to be one product. Say you have 3 different configurable PC -s available and you get 3 orders , to define them for program you need a group id and do define them for fulfilling order is nice to know what type of configuration client has bought

Comment: I see the reason for sku's in general, but as far as I can tell you can't buy a configurable product, only one of its "variants".  I am about to start creating this products and am just confused about what to even enter as a sku.  In my case I am dealing with kites that have different color options.  Each color option has a diff sku,  There is not a sku for the overall product because the sku is connected to the color choice.  any thing else helps, thanks for the info so far.

Comment: you can always think of this type of SKU -s as prefix as it is intended to group stuff and have all the variations use the same prefix like GRKITE01 and then GRKITE01_COLOR_RED and so on. This gives you more power in searching the right items later.

Answer (score 2):

To be pithy, because every "product" needs a human-usable identifier, and that pretty much defines a SKU. You could use the entity_id (PK column) instead, but then you'll just be pushing the question back a layer.

Comment: "configurable products" are no "products" really, it's more of a classification or a group of products.

Answer (score 1):

A valid question, I suppose they did it for consistency.  I think it's a good point that a stock keep unit is a thing, and a configurable product is not a thing .. yet SKU is the one piece of information that is kept constant in say.. importing and exporting.  I guess they did it for uniqueness rather than to be technically correct.  Virtual products wouldn't need skus either, but they are a unit in your system, so they have them.   Is there a technical side to your question, or is it purely philosophical?

Comment: I am asking from both a technical and philisophical point of view.  From a logistics standpoint I have products with color options that have diff skus.  Red has one sku, blue has another.  So I don't even know what I would enter for the config product sku... Philosophically I am trying to understand the point of it as well.  I am rails dev most of the time so this stuff just confuses the crap out of me.  thanks for your help.

Comment: Usually what I do is make the configurable product some schema of the sub products for instance. 

If the simple skus are: 560056 and 560057 I would make the config sku 5600XX  or 5600_Config.  I like the "_Config" because then I can pull them all out in a report.